# When should I hide the Loading Component in React Native FlashList?

Tags: react-native

There is a delay when items are displayed on the screen. That's why I created a Loading component on top of the `Flashlist`. But when should I hide it? How can I make sure it's listed on the screen?

What I want to do is definitely not this; If there is data, hide Loading. Because even if there is data, the items will not be visible for a while.

```js
    const [load, setLoad] = useState(true);
    
    return (
        <View>
            {
                load ?
    
                    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 10 }}>
                        <Text>Loading...</Text>
                    </View>
    
                    :
    
                    null
            }
            <FlashList />
        </View>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you mean **[@shopify/flash-list](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/)**

In `FlatList` we encounter the delay by using `initialNumToRender` but its not supported in flashList.

> There are also FlatList props that would bring no value if ported to
> FlashList due to the differences in their underlying implementation
>
> disableVirtualization  getItemLayout initialNumToRender
> maxToRenderPerBatch  recordInteraction  setNativeProps
> updateCellsBatchingPeriod
>
> We don't currently plan to implement these props.

but there is **[onload](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/usage#onload)** which will be triggered once the items are drawn.

```js
   onLoad: (info: { elapsedTimeInMs: number }) => void;
```

the loading will be hidden once the items are drawn on the screen

```js
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const handleFlashListLoad = (info) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
    };
    
      return (
        <View>
          {isLoading ? (
            <View style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 10 }}>
              <Text>Loading...</Text>
            </View>
          ) : null}
          <FlashList onLoad={handleFlashListLoad} />
        </View>
    )
```

Edit

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';
import { FlashList } from '@shopify/flash-list';

export default function App() {
  const generateData = (num) => {
    return Array.from({ length: num }).map((_, index) => ({
      title: 'new' + index.toString(),
    }));
  };

  const [load, setLoad] = React.useState(true);
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = React.useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(generateData(1000));

  const generateMoreData = (num) => {
    return Array.from({ length: num }).map((_, index) => ({
      title: 'more' + index.toString(),
    }));
  };

  const handleFlashListLoad = (info) => {
    setLoad(false);
  };

  const loadData = (info) => {
    const newData = generateData(200000);
    setData(newData);
  };

  const loadMore = (info) => {
    setRefresh(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      const newData = generateMoreData(5);
      setData((prevState) => [...prevState, ...newData]);
      setRefresh(false);
    }, 2000);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    //loadData();
    //setTimeout(loadMore, 5000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 100 }}>
      {load ? (
        <View>
          <Text>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
      ) : null}
      <FlashList
        data={data}
        extraData={data}
        onLoad={handleFlashListLoad}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            tintColor={'red'}
            refreshing={refresh}
            onRefresh={loadMore}
          />
        }
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'red',
              width: '100%',
              height: 100,
              marginVertical: 2,
            }}>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

to handle the loading you can start with loading and wait the flashList to draw the items then you can hide it by using onLoad... or use refreshControl ... setRefresh once you call load more to show its loading and once you load the items you can set it to false

```
  const loadMore = (info) => {
        setRefresh(true);// show loading to user to wait
        setTimeout(() => {
          const newData = generateMoreData(5);
          setData((prevState) => [...prevState, ...newData]);
          setRefresh(false);// once its loaded hide it 
        }, 2000);
      };
```

I hope this answer your question

Comment: Hi, this run once on first open. How can I make it work when I change the data of the list?

Comment: you can use extraData to tell flashList to re-render for the new items

Comment: I tried but, `handleFlashListLoad` still runs once. Can you give an example?

Comment: Your code was a similar approach to what I did before. I run your code. I just added `console.log()` to the `handleFlashListLoad` function. However it still runs once.